# iOS - Safe Area Layout not work on iOS 9 and iOS 10

Tags: ios

Here is the constraints:

[image]

It works fine on iOS11, but doesn't work on iOS9 and iOS 10.

[image]

You can download the example over [here](https://github.com/lifution/SafeAreaLayoutTest).

#### Note: The UISwitch must be added to the RedView and use the Safe Area Layout.

Comment: please add the image of how you want it to be. what's the expected design? we can't guess the right design. sorry

Comment: Turn off *Safe Area* if you are supporting older version of iOS.

Comment: @TungFam The design is the effect on iOS11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to achieve this? (ios10 on the left and ios 11 on the right)
[image]

If yes, you can do next:

1. remove safe area from red view
2. set top constraint of UISwitch to the safe area of **the view of view controller** but not to the top of the red view.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide

safeAreaLayoutGuide is introduced in iOS 11. No wonder it doesn't work in iOS 9 and 10.

For older versions, consider using layoutMargins property instead.

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
let topPadding = window?.layoutMargins
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and found top constraint of your **Red View** is not correct. Your **Red View** should align top from **Safe Area** instead of superview.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting edgesForExtendedLayout to an empty array for iOS 10 had the desired effect.
Full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51247890/3885491

Answer (score -1):

If you're using storyboards then it would work because Storyboard is backward-compatible. Bare in mind that storyboards hides the difference in the actual code and not good for deep understanding...

---

If you're doing it programmatically then:

See [Safe Area Layout Guide Tutorial](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/)
. SafeArea is available in iOS 11 only. For non-iOS 11 you must use `topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor`.

For more see [On iOS, what are the differences between margins, edge insets, content insets, alignment rects, layout margins, anchors…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796884/on-ios-what-are-the-differences-between-margins-edge-insets-content-insets-a/47614397#47614397)

Comment: Apple told us in [WWDC 2017 Session 412](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/412/) that Storyboards using safe areas are backwards deployable.

Comment: You're right. Just from a pure learning perspective, my answers points out their differences. It's better to *know* their differences and not allow Xcode just do things we don't know of.

Comment: Okay, I will make a schedule to learn their differences, thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: This answer is misleading for the same reason Allen mentions.