# Safe area in xibs broken in iOS 10 [Avoiding Hacks]

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, xib

I've been updating my app to so it can work in iOS 10, 11 and the new iPhone X. I don't use Storyboards, and I've noticed that when using the new safe area guides, everything works as expected on any device that runs iOS 11. However, in iOS 10, it seems that the safe area guides are not being converted to the previous layout guides.

Here's a simple example with just a view aligned to the top, left and right safe area margins:

This is what happens when using xib:

[image]

And with storyboard:

[image]

I have noticed that two people had similar [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46184197/ios-11-safe-area-layout-guide-backwards-compatibility) in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298427/safe-area-layout-guides-in-xib-files-ios-10?noredirect=1&lq=1) and in the [Apple Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87329) but the solutions are hacky and are trying to fight the underlying framework. Is there any oficial solution to this?

Comment: Man it is Apple. In iOS 10 safe area is not broken - it doesn't even exist in iOS <11. And they are lying - I have storyboard and have the same issues